# Socket.io - messages render late and in varied amounts

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets

Followed a tutorial to try to get `socket.io` into my app and I'm having some issues.

I have the server set to 8000 and a proxy on the frontend to go to 8000, but the proxy isn't working. Also when I gave it a shot to switch the server to 3000, running the server shows that it still runs on 8000.

Messages still do go, but with a huge delay and many multiples of the message rendering, amidst my console being full of scary read error text.

For now I just want to have realtime chat with myself so nothing too crazy.

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const socket = require("socket.io");
const io = socket(server);
// .listen(server);

io.on("connection", socket => {
    socket.emit("your id", socket.id);
    socket.on("send message", body => {
        io.emit("message", body)
    })
})


server.listen(8000, () => console.log("server is running on port 8000"));
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import './Data.css';

// import Chatty from '../../Pages/Chatty';

const Data = props => {

    //Database Stuff here
    const [yourID, setYourID] = useState();
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState([]);

    const socketRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
       socketRef.current = io.connect('/');
       
       socketRef.current.on("your id", id => {
           setYourID(id);
       })


       socketRef.current.on("message", (message) => {
        recievedMessage(message);
       })
    });

    function recievedMessage(message) {
        setMessages(oldMsgs => [...oldMsgs, message]);
    }

    function sendMessage(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const messageObject = {
            body: message,
            id: yourID,
        };
        setMessage("")
        socketRef.current.emit("send message", messageObject);
    }

    function handleChange(e) {
        setMessage(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
    //Send down the info, render the chat shit
            <div className="Page">
                <div className="Container">
                    {messages.map((message, index) => {
                        if (message.id === yourID) {
                            return (
                                <div className="MyRow" key={index}>
                                    <div className="MyMessage" >
                                        {message.body}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        }
                        return (
                            <div key={index} style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-start' }} >
                                <div className="PartnerMessage" >
                                    {message.body}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={sendMessage}>
                    <input style={{ width: '100%' }} value={message} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Say something..." />
                    <button className="Button">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
    )
}

export default Data;
```

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
  "secure": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^3.0.1"
  },
```

Comment: have you installed `socket.io`? its not in the package.json

Comment: *multiples of the message rendering, amidst my console being full of scary read error text.* care to share them errors or must we guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, really silly honestly. I didn't set the dependency of the useEffect hook so it kept running over and over. I set it to an empty array and voila!

From

```
    useEffect(() => {
       socketRef.current = io.connect('/');
       
       socketRef.current.on("your id", id => {
           setYourID(id);
       })

       socketRef.current.on("message", (message) => {
        recievedMessage(message);
       })
    });
```

to

```
    useEffect(() => {
       socketRef.current = io.connect('/');
       
       socketRef.current.on("your id", id => {
           setYourID(id);
       })

       socketRef.current.on("message", (message) => {
        recievedMessage(message);
       })
    }, []);
```